# node-red, MySQL error

Tags: mysql, node-red

Get an error when writing to the database

The function for it:

```
var newMsg = { payload: msg.payload };
newMsg.topic="insert into MyTable (a,b,c,d,e,f,g) values (newMsg.payload)"
```

The incoming payload debug shows

```
payload: "B0:AC:A2:AC:07:F4","Ready","893901","860990","online","876","333"
```

The error I get from the database node (nore-red-node-mysql) is

> "Error: ER_WRONG_VALUE_COUNT_ON_ROW: Column count doesn't match value
>   count at row 1"

The strange thing to me is that if I try a

```
newMsg.topic="insert into MyTable (a,b,c,d,e,f,g) values (\"B0:AC:A2:AC:07:F4\",\"Ready\",\"893901\",\"860990\",\"online\",\"876\",\"333\")"
```

it works perfectly...

Where is the trick?

Comment: Edit the question to add exactly which database node you are using, `node-red-node-mysql` or `node-red-contrib-sqldbs` or `node-red-contrib-odbc`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no trick.

This is because the **node-red-node-mysql** and **node-red-contrib-sqldbs** nodes do not do any query substitution.

This means that what gets sent to the database is exactly what is in the `msg.topic` field. In this case that would have been:

```
insert into MyTable (a,b,c,d,e,f,g) values (newMsg.payload)
```

Which mysql will read as trying to pass a single value to a query expecting 7 values.

You will have to build the full query (and do your own variable escaping if needed) in a function node before passing the message to the database node.

Comment: yeah, that's why I reached as a conclusion too after a million of tries...Any sample code for a newbie?

Comment: The answer to your previous question has everything you need to solve this problem

Answer (score 0):

at the end I solved it this way:

```
  var data = msg.payload.split(",");
  msg.payload = {};
  msg.payload.a=data[0];
  msg.payload.b=data[1];
  msg.payload.c=data[2];
  msg.payload.d=data[3];
  msg.payload.e=data[4];
  msg.payload.f=data[5];
  msg.payload.g=data[6];
  insert into MyTable (a,b,c,d,e,f,g) values ('" + data[0] + "','" + data[1] + "','" + data[2] + "','" + data[3] + "','" + data[4] + "','" + data[5] + "','" + data[6] + "')";
  return msg;
```